# not able to run image from windows docker from command line but runs from VisualStudio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, docker-for-windows

I am converting an old WCF project into an docker solution using VS2019. It does run but not sure what is happening when I click on green play button.

1) There is port mapping is done automatically eventhoug the docker file does not have expose

2) there seems to be some form of nat happening automatically

3) when i try to run the image from command line it does not seem to work

```
docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:60636:80 wcfservice1:dev
```

When I run from Visual studio 2019

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       PORTS                                           NAMES
fd1b4b1a2824   wcfservice1:dev             0.0.0.0:54640->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:54639->808/tcp   tender_murdock
ba4f04195de8   ssosystemserviceserver:dev  0.0.0.0:61329->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:61328->808/tcp   musing_liskov
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, I am trying to run web.api. Some docker images are created but running them on command prompt does not work. I am on Windows 10 pro. Visual studio runs a very long command that has "-dt" and many -v in it. I am simply trying to go docker run -p 8080:0 <imageId>. Using Image name does not work, and using -n or -name to specify a name does not work either. Something may not be right with my docker settings/installation. I will share once I figure out.